# How to change ZOrder in Apache POI for Pptx shapes

Tags: apache-poi

Is it possible to change the Z-Order of a shape in a pptx slide with Apache POI?

If not directly, any workaround?

Comment: The quick answer is, it depends on the order of the p:* elements within the p:spTree element - the first element is the lowest. If you want to modify you need to access it over the XSLFSheet::getSpTree() method, which is protected, therefore you need to modify the POI implementation yourself.
If I would implement it, I would try to use a XmlCursor to shift the shape elements.
In the long term, I might implement it and provide an API for it, but I don't guarantee you a prompt delivery ...

Comment: That would be neat, thank you, in the meanwhile I have found a workaround by copying the source slide, deleting the last elements from the source and the first elements from the clone, placing the target element, and then appending content from the clone slide (and finally deleting the clone slide)